# Optimize recode in base R

Tags: r, radix

I am a recoding a variable based on some rather long strings, here exemplified by the strings A, B, C, D, E, and G. I was wondering if there is a way to recode this with out having to repeat the reference to `df$foo` 12 times using base R? Maybe there is some some smarter faster way routhe I could explore? is this is really the smartest way to do it in R?

```
df <- data.frame(
  foo = 1000:1010,
  bar = letters[1:11])
df  
    foo bar
1  1000   a
2  1001   b
3  1002   c
4  1003   d
5  1004   e
6  1005   f
7  1006   g
8  1007   h
9  1008   i
10 1009   j
11 1010   k

A  <- c(1002)
B  <- c(1007, 1008)
C  <- c(1001, 1003)
D  <- c(1004, 1006)
E  <- c(1000, 1005)
G  <- c(1010, 1009)

df$foo[df$foo %in% A] <- 1
df$foo[df$foo %in% B] <- 2
df$foo[df$foo %in% C] <- 3
df$foo[df$foo %in% D] <- 4
df$foo[df$foo %in% E] <- 5
df$foo[df$foo %in% G] <- 7
df
   foo bar
1    5   a
2    3   b
3    1   c
4    3   d
5    4   e
6    5   f
7    4   g
8    2   h
9    2   i
10   7   j
11   7   k
```

### Update on 2013-03-11 05:28:061Z,

I've rewritten the five solutions to functions to be able to compare them using the microbenchmark package and the result is that Tyler Rinker and flodel's solutions is the fastest solutions (see results below), not to say this question is about speed alone. I am also looking for conciseness and *smartness* in the solution. Out of curiosity I also added a solution using the `Recode` function from the car package.  Please feel free to let me know if I could have rewritten the solutions in a more optimal way or if the the microbenchmark package is not the best way to compare these functions.

```
df <- data.frame(
  foo = sample(1000:1010, 1e5+22, replace = TRUE),
  bar = rep(letters, 3847))
str(df)

A  <- c(1002)
B  <- c(1007, 1008)
C  <- c(1001, 1003)
D  <- c(1004, 1006)
E  <- c(1000, 1005)
G  <- c(1010, 1009)

# juba's solution
juba <- function(df,foo) within(df, {foo[foo %in% A] <- 1; foo[foo %in% B] <- 2;foo[foo %in% C] <- 3;foo[foo %in% D] <- 4;foo[foo %in% E] <- 5;foo[foo %in% G] <- 7})
# Arun's solution
Arun <- function(df,x) factor(df[,x], levels=c(A,B,C,D,E,G), labels=c(1, rep(c(2:5, 7), each=2)))
# flodel's solution
flodel <- function(df,x) rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), sapply(list(A, B, C, D, E, G), length))[match(df[,x], unlist(list(A, B, C, D, E, G)))]
# Tyler Rinker's solution
TylerRinker <- function(df,x)  data.frame(vals = unlist(list(A  = c(1002),B  = c(1007, 1008),C  = c(1001, 1003),D  = c(1004, 1006),E  = c(1000, 1005), G = c(1010, 1009))), labs = c(1, rep(c(2:5, 7), each=2)))[match(df[,x], unlist(list(A  = c(1002),B  = c(1007, 1008),C  = c(1001, 1003),D  = c(1004, 1006),E  = c(1000, 1005), G = c(1010, 1009)))), 2] 
# agstudy's solution
agstudy <- function(df,foo) merge(df,data.frame(foo=unlist(list(A, B, C, D, E, G)), val =rep((1:7)[-6],rapply(list(A, B, C, D, E, G), length))))
# Recode from the car package
ReINcar <- function(df,x) Recode(df[,x], "A='A'; B='B'; C='C'; D='D'; E='E'; G='G'")

# install.packages("microbenchmark", dependencies = TRUE)
require(microbenchmark)

# run test
res <- microbenchmark(juba(df, foo), Arun(df, 1), flodel(df, 1), TylerRinker(df,1) ,agstudy(df, foo), ReINcar(df, 1), times = 25)
There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them) # warning duo to x's solution

## Print results:
print(res)
```

the numbers,

```
   Unit: milliseconds
                   expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
          juba(df, foo)  37.944355  39.521603  41.987174  46.385974  79.559750    25
            Arun(df, 1)  23.833334  24.115776  24.648842  26.987431  55.466448    25
          flodel(df, 1)   3.586179   3.637024   3.956814   6.468735  28.404166    25
     TylerRinker(df, 1)   3.919563   4.115994   4.529926   5.532688   8.508956    25
       agstudy(df, foo) 301.487732 324.641734 334.801005 352.753496 415.421212    25
         ReINcar(df, 1)  73.655566  77.903088  81.745037 101.038791 125.158208    25


### Plot results:
boxplot(res)
```

#### Box Plot of microbenchmark results,

[image: Box Plot of microbenchmark results]

Comment: There are duplicated values in A and B. Is this right?

Comment: @Arun, nope. That is a typo on my part. I've updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: You can also take a look at the `recode` functions from the `memisc` and `car` packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a general (scalable) approach, very fast too:

```
sets <- list(A, B, C, D, E, G)
vals <-    c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)

keys   <- unlist(sets)
values <- rep(vals, sapply(sets, length))
df$foo <- values[match(df$foo, keys)]
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a crude benchmark test where I compare your solution to the four other solutions on speed. Please feel free to correct the function I have written used to represent your solution in the test.

Answer (score 4):

Using `within` can help you save some keystrokes :

```
df <- within(df,
       {foo[foo %in% A] <- 1;
        foo[foo %in% B] <- 2;
        foo[foo %in% C] <- 3;
        foo[foo %in% D] <- 4;
        foo[foo %in% E] <- 5;
        foo[foo %in% G] <- 7})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like that you managed to remove 12 * `df$`, but it's still somewhat repetitive on `'foo'. Could you explain the use of `;`?

Comment: @EricFail `within` takes an expression as second argument. Here we want to execute several statements, so I pass them to `within` enclosed into braces `{` and separated with `;`. It's the same way you can pass several statements in one line to R.

Comment: It might be an operating system issue, but on my machine (*NIX) I the code works perfectly fine without the `;`. I mean, you do have your code on separate lines.

Comment: @EricFail Oups, sorry, you're perfectly right, it works without the `;`. These are needed only if the statements are on the same line. Thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: I've updated my question with a crude benchmark test where I compare your solution to the four other solutions on speed. Please feel free to correct the function I have written used to represent your solution in the test.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do: (Edited)

```
> df$foo <- factor(df$foo, levels=c(A,B,C,D,E,G), labels=c(1, rep(c(2:5, 7), each=2)))

# Warning message:
# In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
#   duplicated levels will not be allowed in factors anymore

#    foo bar
# 1    5   a
# 2    3   b
# 3    1   c
# 4    3   d
# 5    4   e
# 6    5   f
# 7    4   g
# 8    2   h
# 9    2   i
# 10   7   j
# 11   7   k
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I've updated my question and now I get a different error (in regard to the label length). I find your solution very interesting!

Comment: I've edited the solution for the new data. Seems like the warning still persists and is because the levels do not have unique labels. But it still returns the correct result.

Comment: Thanks, though I must admit that the warning makes me a little nervous.

Comment: If you do after this, once again: `df$foo <- factor(df$foo)`, the levels of factors get restored. So, I don't think it is an issue. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: I've updated my question with a crude benchmark test where I compare your solution to the four other solutions on speed. Please feel free to correct the function I have written used to represent your solution in the test.

Answer (score 3):

My approach (lose the A, B, C... all together but I see flodel's is very similar).

```
keyL <- list(
    A  = c(1002),
    B  = c(1007, 1008),
    C  = c(1001, 1003),
    D  = c(1004, 1006),
    E  = c(1000, 1005),
    G  = c(1010, 1009)
)

key <- data.frame(vals = unlist(keyL), labs = c(1, rep(c(2:5, 7), each=2)))

df$foo2 <- key[match(df$foo, key$vals), 2]
```

I don't like writing over old columns so created a new one.  I'd also store the key as a named list.

Comment: I've updated my question with a crude benchmark test where I compare your solution to the four other solutions on speed. Please feel free to correct the function I have written used to represent your solution in the test.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `merge` , very similar to @flodel and @Tyler approach

```
sets <- list(A, B, C, D, E, G)
df.code = data.frame(foo=unlist(sets),
                     val =rep((1:7)[-6],rapply(sets, length)))
> merge(df,df.code)
    foo bar val
1  1000   a   5
2  1001   b   3
3  1002   c   1
4  1003   d   3
5  1004   e   4
6  1005   f   5
7  1006   g   4
8  1007   h   2
9  1008   i   2
10 1009   j   7
11 1010   k   7
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a crude benchmark test where I compare your solution to the four other solutions on speed. Please feel free to correct the function I have written used to represent your solution in the test.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, albeit using a slightly different format.  And it will likely be the fastest method.

```
library(data.table)

## Create the sample data:
dt <- data.table(foo=sample(1000:1010, 1e5+22, replace = TRUE), bar=rep(letters, 3847), key="foo")

## Create the table that maps the old value of foo to the new one:
dt.recode<-data.table(foo_old=1000:1010, foo_new=c(5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L), key="foo_old")

## Show the result of the join/merge between the original and recoded table:
## (not necesary if you only want to update the original table)
dt[dt.recode]
##       foo bar foo_new
##  1: 1000   a       5
##  2: 1001   b       3
##  3: 1002   c       1
##  4: 1003   d       3
##  5: 1004   e       4
##  6: 1005   f       5
##  7: 1006   g       4
##  8: 1007   h       2
##  9: 1008   i       2
## 10: 1009   j       7
## 11: 1010   k       7

## Same as above, but updates the value of foo in the original table:
dt[dt.recode,foo:=foo_new][]
##     foo bar
##  1:   5   a
##  2:   3   b
##  3:   1   c
##  4:   3   d
##  5:   4   e
##  6:   5   f
##  7:   4   g
##  8:   2   h
##  9:   2   i
## 10:   7   j
## 11:   7   k
```

Here's how to convert your data frame to a data table (and add the key that is necessary for the join later), if you prefer that rather than creating the data table from scratch:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt,foo)
```

I'm not sure how you want to count the timing with this method, but assuming dt and dt.recode already exist and have been keyed, then running the single line that updates the table showed 0 elapsed time on my system.

Also, if your A, B, C, D, E, G groups have any intrinsic meaning, I would add them as a column to your original table. Then you could join on this field, and dt.recode would only need 6 rows (assuming you have six groups).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did, however, already use [flodel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15317417/1305688) that he posted on Mar 10. Regardless, I appreciate your input!